# Can I see what happens in PhantomJS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, phantomjs

Sometimes, when running automated tests in PhantomJS using Cucumber for Rails 4, it would be really, really useful to actually sit in front of my screen, look in a window, and see exactly what the browser is doing.

There are times when your code is right and your test is right, but testing fails intermittently nonetheless. It's often because of a script, or an animation, or some CSS that gets in the way. But seeing a screenshot, drilling into a DOM inspector, or using the debugger is not enough to catch those edge cases.

Is there any way to have a window looking at what PhantomJS is doing in the background? It could be something in X Window, or running in a VNC Server, etc. Anything visual would greatly help with debugging, especially in with those finicky details.

I found a little program called [PhantomVNC](https://github.com/ralfthewise/phantomvnc), but it's not telling me much on how it works. It looks like something just feeding a series of screenshots through VNC.

I tried PhantomJS and Capybara-WebKit, but neither of those headless browsers other a "head" option. Selenium-WebDriver seems complicated to set up and only seems to work with a full browser like Firefox, and that may cause more problems than it solves.

If you have any ideas, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure specifically about Cuc/Rails - but I specifically have a second chrome/webdriver Virtual Machine for this. I use PhantomJS specifically for the headless automatic acceptance testing, but when there is an issue with the tests and I'm trying to diagnose it can be helpful to view the browser live.

In other words, spin up a Ubuntu desktop VM, install chrome, install selenium server and the chrome webdriver. Log in to the VM, open chrome, make sure selenium is running, then configure your test suite to connect to the selenium webdriver service (usually port :4444) of this instance. Run your tests and you should be able to watch the chrome instance on the VM.